# weka serialized model file too big

Tags: serialization, weka, random-forest

I've build a random forest classifier using weka (in java).
I saved a serialized classifier to disk. However, the serialized file is too big (approx. 100 MB). Moreover, the file is getting bigger in case I trained over more instances, so I guess the serialized model save also the data. 
Is there another way to save a weka classifier? And with smaller output file (in general I assume the size should depend only on the model architecture).
I've used the following to serilization, all produce the same file size:
Weka.core.serializationHelper.write(),  Debug.saveToFile() , ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()

Answer (score 1):

You can save it as a GZIP. Usually it is much more compact.

```
            File f = new File(path);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(yourClassifier);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            gzipOutputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
```

To load it you can use:

```
            File f = new File(path);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileInputStream);
            ObjectInputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectInputStream(gzipInputStream);
            Classifier mlClassifier = (Classifier) objectOutputStream.readObject();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            gzipInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
```

Comment: Its reduce it from 73 mb to only 13 mb - so it's worked.
However, the model itself still take a lot of memory (cause  java heap error). is there any way to remove the samples from the weka classifier ?

Comment: You can train a more compact model. What classifier are you currently using?

Comment: Random Forest.  I don't think that the big size is duo to model capacity (num of trees etc.). It shouldn’t be depend on the train size.

Comment: The number of instances affect the depth of the trees.